# Force compatibility IE10 on localhost

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility

How can I make my localhost in IE10 use the compatibility mode defined in meta?

Windows thinks that the users who use localhost don't want compatibility but we do, and we want to force it on our clients. It works fine when we visit the hostname, the problem is on localhost. Also fine for Chrome and Firefox.

Greetings
Jeff

Comment: why would you want to use compatibility mode? IE10 is pretty good with standards, so if it works in chrome and firefox, why would it not work with IE10 standards mode but it does in compat mode? And if that is the case, it sounds like you should probably fix the bug in your code rather than trying to rely on compat mode (bear in mind that IE's compat mode isn't really very good at being fully compatible with the old IE versions anyway, so it's not generally a good idea to use it unless you absolutely *have* to)

Comment: The product is deployed but is no longer supported by the supplier. So it was made for IE8 and works fine there. When we are in IE10 and visit the application using localhost (compatibility mode isn't used) it looks awful.

Comment: You should probably include the meta tag that you're using in the question so we can see it. btw, IE typically defaults to compat mode for localhost (thanks to the "use compat mode on the intranet" flag which defaults to being switched on); are you sure it isn't doing something nasty like dropping into IE7-compat? What mode do the dev-tools tell you?

Comment: The webapp is using frames so they aren't useful... It says IE10 compat view on http:hostname and IE10 on the http:localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

site on intranet wa working good but my localhost site was not properly working with ie 10 but this solution was worked for me;

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=6">
```

instead of the

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

did the trick for localhost. And make sure it's in all the frames.